# Trouble getting VPN to work with my router, possible WPAD issue

Tags: vpn, wireless-router, tcpip

I've been having a problem using Cisco Anyconnect VPN on Windows 7 with my wireless router (a Belkin F5D8635-4 v1 Wireless N). It connects sometimes, but often won't until the router has been reset. Wireless card is a Realtek RTL8192SE 802.11B/G/N. Whipped out Network Monitor, and this seems to be what's happening when it fails to connect.

```
125 5   7:48:44 AM 6/2/2013 2.7738830       PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.1 DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x1D29, QUERY (Standard query), Query  for vpn.caltech.edu of type Host Addr on class Internet    {DNS:2, UDP:1, IPv4:3}
121 6   7:48:44 AM 6/2/2013 2.7750846       PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.1 DNS DNS:QueryId = 0xB1DF, QUERY (Standard query), Query  for wpad.Belkin of type Host Addr on class Internet    {DNS:4, UDP:3, IPv4:3}
141 7   7:48:44 AM 6/2/2013 2.7751546       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x1D29, QUERY (Standard query), Response - Success, 192.41.208.57     {DNS:2, UDP:1, IPv4:3}
196 8   7:48:44 AM 6/2/2013 2.7761219       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DNS DNS:QueryId = 0xB1DF, QUERY (Standard query), Response - Name Error     {DNS:4, UDP:3, IPv4:3}
```

Stops at the Name Error in response to wpad.Belkin DNS query. Afraid I don't know enough about TCP/IP to understand what this means. Not sure if it's a problem with my ISP (Virgin Broadband). I've tried switching to the OpenDNS servers in the router. Have also had similar problems with another router, though I didn't look at the packets for that one. Found some people with similar problems elsewhere, but no resolutions. Any ideas? Thanks!

BTW the router log looks like this - realize most of the port-scan alerts are bogus, but wondering if they have anything to do with the resolution problem.

```
Jun 2 05:58:33 localhost user.crit syslog: User from 192.168.2.2 time out 
Jun 2 06:02:28 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1864]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:02:28 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1864]: received REQUEST 
Jun 2 06:02:28 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1864]: sending ACK to 192.168.2.2 
Jun 2 06:02:47 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1864]: received REQUEST 
Jun 2 06:02:47 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1864]: sending ACK to 192.168.2.2 
Jun 2 06:07:28 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1864]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:08:17 localhost local0.info udhcpd[8647]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:13:17 localhost local0.info udhcpd[8647]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:13:37 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14800]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:18:37 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14800]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:18:53 localhost local0.info udhcpd[20975]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:23:53 localhost local0.info udhcpd[20975]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:24:12 localhost local0.info udhcpd[27065]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:29:12 localhost local0.info udhcpd[27065]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:29:38 localhost local0.info udhcpd[933]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:33:00 localhost user.crit syslog: User from 192.168.2.2 login success ! 
Jun 2 06:34:38 localhost local0.info udhcpd[933]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:34:56 localhost local0.info udhcpd[7117]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:39:56 localhost local0.info udhcpd[7117]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:41:07 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14308]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:43:14 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14308]: received REQUEST 
Jun 2 06:43:14 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14308]: sending ACK to 192.168.2.2 
Jun 2 06:46:07 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14308]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:46:32 localhost local0.info udhcpd[20535]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:46:45 localhost user.crit syslog: User from 192.168.2.2 time out 
Jun 2 06:51:32 localhost local0.info udhcpd[20535]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:52:36 localhost local0.info udhcpd[27617]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 06:57:36 localhost local0.info udhcpd[27617]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 06:58:19 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1757]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:03:19 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1757]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:03:35 localhost local0.info udhcpd[7847]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:08:35 localhost local0.info udhcpd[7847]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:09:06 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14284]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:14:06 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14284]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:14:26 localhost local0.info udhcpd[20479]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:19:26 localhost local0.info udhcpd[20479]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:20:25 localhost local0.info udhcpd[27465]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:25:25 localhost local0.info udhcpd[27465]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:25:41 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1148]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:30:41 localhost local0.info udhcpd[1148]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:31:04 localhost local0.info udhcpd[7465]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:36:04 localhost local0.info udhcpd[7465]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:37:38 localhost local0.info udhcpd[15008]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:42:38 localhost local0.info udhcpd[15008]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:44:53 localhost local0.info udhcpd[23354]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:46:40 localhost user.crit syslog: User from 192.168.2.2 login success ! 
Jun 2 07:49:53 localhost local0.info udhcpd[23354]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 07:54:55 localhost local0.info udhcpd[2936]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 07:59:55 localhost local0.info udhcpd[2936]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 08:04:57 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14605]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 08:09:08 localhost user.crit syslog: User from 192.168.2.2 time out 
Jun 2 08:09:57 localhost local0.info udhcpd[14605]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 08:12:49 localhost local0.info udhcpd[23749]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 08:17:49 localhost local0.info udhcpd[23749]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 08:19:49 localhost local0.info udhcpd[31891]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 08:24:49 localhost local0.info udhcpd[31891]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 08:25:01 localhost local0.info udhcpd[5533]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 08:30:01 localhost local0.info udhcpd[5533]: Timed out. Exiting 
Jun 2 08:35:03 localhost local0.info udhcpd[17262]: udhcpd (v0.9.9-pre) started 
Jun 2 08:37:40 localhost user.crit syslog: User from 192.168.2.2 login success ! 

Firewall log:
Jun 2 03:05:40 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 03:05:41 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 03:05:42 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 03:06:45 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the UDP protocol. 
Jun 2 03:06:46 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 108.160.162.37. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 03:15:19 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 66.235.142.57. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 03:15:25 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 66.235.142.57. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 03:17:47 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 03:17:48 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 66.235.142.57. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 03:17:50 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 03:17:51 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 03:47:53 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 32.58.65.146. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 04:47:50 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 208.85.209.17. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 05:17:50 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 198.252.206.25. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 05:47:53 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 06:17:51 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol 
Jun 2 06:47:50 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 50.18.252.211. Source port is 33087, and destination port is 61440 which use the TCP protocol. 
Jun 2 07:17:51 localhost user.alert kernel: PORT_SCANNER-ATTACK detected from 194.168.4.100. Use ICMP protocol
```

Edit: for reference, here is a successful connection. The Name Error also occurs there, but doesn't seem to matter.

```
121 3   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.4943862       PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.1 DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x3506, QUERY (Standard query), Query  for wpad.Belkin of type Host Addr on class Internet    {DNS:3, UDP:2, IPv4:1}
392 4   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.4986302       PS-THINKPAD     255.255.255.255 DHCP    DHCP:Request, MsgType = INFORM, TransactionID = 0x0EF1238D  {DHCP:6, UDP:11, IPv4:1}
196 5   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.4989521       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x3506, QUERY (Standard query), Response - Name Error     {DNS:3, UDP:2, IPv4:1}
134 6   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.4995933       FE80:0:0:0:318A:6E05:B12F:106   FF02:0:0:0:0:0:1:3  LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0xADB2, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:8, IPv6:7}
114 7   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.5008695       PS-THINKPAD     224.0.0.252 LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0xADB2, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:10, IPv4:9}
640 8   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.5035848       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DHCP    DHCP:Reply, MsgType = ACK, TransactionID = 0x0EF1238D   {DHCP:6, UDP:11, IPv4:1}
125 9   9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.5363506       PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.1 DNS DNS:QueryId = 0xEDCE, QUERY (Standard query), Query  for vpn.caltech.edu of type Host Addr on class Internet    {DNS:13, UDP:12, IPv4:1}
141 10  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.5377057       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DNS DNS:QueryId = 0xEDCE, QUERY (Standard query), Response - Success, 192.41.208.57     {DNS:13, UDP:12, IPv4:1}
134 11  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.5592248       FE80:0:0:0:318A:6E05:B12F:106   FF02:0:0:0:0:0:1:3  LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0x9634, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:14, IPv6:7}
114 12  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.5619238       PS-THINKPAD     224.0.0.252 LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0x9634, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:15, IPv4:9}
134 13  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.6067949       FE80:0:0:0:318A:6E05:B12F:106   FF02:0:0:0:0:0:1:3  LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0xADB2, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:8, IPv6:7}
114 14  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.6068906       PS-THINKPAD     224.0.0.252 LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0xADB2, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:10, IPv4:9}
134 15  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.6692384       FE80:0:0:0:318A:6E05:B12F:106   FF02:0:0:0:0:0:1:3  LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0x9634, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:14, IPv6:7}
114 16  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.6693280       PS-THINKPAD     224.0.0.252 LLMNR   LLMNR:QueryId = 0x9634, Standard, Query  for wpad of type Host Addr on class Internet   {UDP:15, IPv4:9}
142 17  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.8099953   System  PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.255   NbtNs   NbtNs:Query Request for WPAD   <0x00> Workstation Service   {UDP:17, IPv4:16}
142 18  9:39:59 AM 6/2/2013 2.8722391   System  PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.255   NbtNs   NbtNs:Query Request for WPAD   <0x00> Workstation Service   {UDP:17, IPv4:16}
142 19  9:40:00 AM 6/2/2013 3.5738980   System  PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.255   NbtNs   NbtNs:Query Request for WPAD   <0x00> Workstation Service   {UDP:17, IPv4:16}
142 20  9:40:00 AM 6/2/2013 3.6362705   System  PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.255   NbtNs   NbtNs:Query Request for WPAD   <0x00> Workstation Service   {UDP:17, IPv4:16}
142 21  9:40:01 AM 6/2/2013 4.3382645   System  PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.255   NbtNs   NbtNs:Query Request for WPAD   <0x00> Workstation Service   {UDP:17, IPv4:16}
142 22  9:40:01 AM 6/2/2013 4.4006818   System  PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.255   NbtNs   NbtNs:Query Request for WPAD   <0x00> Workstation Service   {UDP:17, IPv4:16}
125 23  9:40:02 AM 6/2/2013 5.2251198       PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.1 DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x717, QUERY (Standard query), Query  for vpn.caltech.edu of type AAAA on class Internet  {DNS:19, UDP:18, IPv4:1}
181 24  9:40:02 AM 6/2/2013 5.2447957       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x717, QUERY (Standard query), Response - Success     {DNS:19, UDP:18, IPv4:1}
125 25  9:40:02 AM 6/2/2013 5.2469250       PS-THINKPAD     192.168.2.1 DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x831C, QUERY (Standard query), Query  for vpn.caltech.edu of type AAAA on class Internet {DNS:21, UDP:20, IPv4:1}
181 26  9:40:02 AM 6/2/2013 5.2485386       192.168.2.1 PS-THINKPAD     DNS DNS:QueryId = 0x831C, QUERY (Standard query), Response - Success    {DNS:21, UDP:20, IPv4:1}
116 27  9:40:02 AM 6/2/2013 5.3215829   vpnui.exe   PS-THINKPAD     vpn.caltech.edu TCP TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=49200, DstPort=HTTPS(443), PayloadLen=0, Seq=3900950642, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x2 ) = 8192    {TCP:23, IPv4:22}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. I made several adjustments, but didn't have the chance to test them all individually (I share the connection with someone else who uses the BIG-IP Edge Client VPN for work, which was also not working properly), so I'll just throw out everything - hopefully it will help someone else with the same problem. Firstly, I disabled UPnP on the router. I found this suggestion in an answer to someone else's problem, and suspect it was the main culprit. Also, running the tool [here](http://www.rapid7.com/resources/free-security-software-downloads/universal-plug-and-play-jan-2013.jsp) showed that the implementation of UPnP on the router was insecure, which was further motivation. I also disabled WPS (another suggestion). I set the MTU size on the router and in Windows to 1500. I also set the router to wireless n only (no b or g). Finally I tried several different versions of drivers for my network card, since they have always been unstable, and cause intermittent DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE BSODs. The other person sharing the connection didn't change their drivers, however, so the only way this could have helped is if my card was somehow tying up the router, which seems unlikely. It didn't help the stability unfortunately, but that too seems to have been later eased by disabling some unneeded options in the Wireless Network Connection Properties, such as Vlan, Link-Layer Discovery, and TCP-IP 6. Not the most satisfying solution, but seems to be working so far (fingers crossed). I intend to do a clean reinstall when I get the time.